# Typing capital delta using ALT code in Windows

Tags: special-characters

I was trying to type the capital delta using the ALT code given [here](https://www.keynotesupport.com/internet/special-characters-greek-letters-symbols.shtml). But when I type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>916</kbd>, I get "ö" instead of the capital delta. Why is this happening? How may I type the capital delta?

Operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Can't explain why (I get the same), but ALT + 30 seems to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks. ALT+30 gives ▲ which is not exactly capital delta but it will work for informal things.

Comment: In MS Word, you get the delta. In Notepad, you get ö.

Comment: I am mainly interested in typing it in the browser (Brave a chromium based browser).